# Android: Disable soft keyboard at all EditTexts

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working on a dialog at Android with a few `EditText`s.
I've put this line at the `onCreate()` in order to disable the soft keyboard:

```
Keypad.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

The problem is that it works only when the dialog appear and doing nothing.
When I move to the next `EditText`, the keyboard appears and not going down.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: why would you want this?

Comment: I have keypad of my own that I want to use, I don't want the soft keyboard go up every time I click an EditText

Answer (score 26, accepted):

create your own class that extends `EditText` and override the `onCheckIsTextEditor()`:

```
public class NoImeEditText extends EditText {
    public NoImeEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It prevents me from running findViewById(). I get class cast exception.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I don't want to disable the EditText, I have keypad of my own that I wrote and want to use it.

Comment: you will need to define the edit text as a NoImeEditText  in the xml (which is your custom edittext), then NoImeEditText et=(NoImeEditText) findViewById(R.id.itsId) should work. you could handle onFocusChange and if et.hasFocus() show your keypad.

Comment: I tried it now and I get another excpetion.
I think the XML can't find the new EditText.

Exception:
04-27 14:59:39.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3006): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.NoImeEditText in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.keypadTest-2.apk]

Comment: in the layout xml use a fully qualified reference to your custom control: <com.yourpackge.path.NoImeEdit android:id="@+id/custControl"...

Comment: It worked, Thanks!
But Now I can't see the cursor. Is there a way to bring it back?

Comment: in the same place you make your keypad appear, you could try yourCustomEditText.setCursorVisible(true) (and accept the answer if it works :) )

Comment: Interesting  - I just created a test project with one custom control, and the cursor appears everytime i give that custom EditText focus.  (without needing to do the setCursorVisible())

Comment: I don't know, I have EditTexts without a cursor and I move between them by touch or with requestFocus(), but still have no cursor.

Comment: Has cursor problem in some devices.

Comment: Constructor name is wrong in your code (or class name). It should be NoImeEditText.

Answer (score 35):

If you take look on onCheckIsTextEditor() method implementation (in TextView), it looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
    return mInputType != EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL;
}
```

This means you don't have to subclass, you can just:

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

I tried setting **android:inputType="none"** in layout xml but it didn't work for me, so I did it programmatically.

Comment: when I use this only the first line of text is visible :( . not all data is shown.

Comment: in some devices, programmatically set null not work.

Comment: This will prevent any touch interactions with the EditText (i.e. long-press and select).  That might not be desired effect many developers want...

Answer (score 22):

Try this out..

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);      
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)   
{  
    edittext.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);  
    edittext.setTextIsSelectable(true);  
}
```

Comment: Great! Text still has cursor and selectable, but what's with api 9?

Comment: Hi Aleksey..Thanks....!!..'edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);' worked perfectly for APi 8....but when i tested in API14, it didnt work.....thats why i added the If condition......

Comment: Thanks, was searching for a way to make edittext contents selectable after making it not-editable.

Comment: Works perfectly in combination with:         editText.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL);

Answer (score 5):

I have been looking for solutions to this all day, and I came across this approach. I'm putting it here because it seems to answer this question perfectly.

```
EditText et = ... // your EditText
et.setKeyListener(null) //makes the EditText non-editable so, it acts like a TextView.
```

No need to subclass. The main difference between this and making your EditText non-focusable, is that the EditText still has its own cursor - you can select text, etc. All it does is suppress the IME from popping up its own soft keyboard.

Comment: I wanted to disable the EditText but still have the setOnClickListener working. This worked good in that case.

Answer (score 5):

Call `TextView.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false)`. This method is documented since API level 21, but it's already there since API level 16 (it's just hidden from JavaDoc). I use it with API level 16 in an AlertDialog in combination with `dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)`.

In API level 14, there is a hidden method `setSoftInputShownOnFocus()` which seems to have the same purpose, but I have not tested that.

The advantage over `InputType.TYPE_NULL` is, that all the normal input types can be used (e.g. for password input) and the touch event positions the cursor at the correct spot within the text.

Answer (score 4):

Its been some time since this post, but here is a simple method which worked for me: in the xml, in the `EditText` properties, do: `android:focusable="false"`. Now the keyboard will not popup even if the user clicks on it. This is useful if you are providing your own keypad.

Answer (score 2):

Know its too late, but have you tried the following setting to EditText in your layout ?

```
android:inputType="none"
```

**UPDATE**

Use,

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)
editText.setFocusable(false)
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The keyboard still goes up with this property. Did it work for you?

Comment: My bad. It doesn't work! Was using a tab emulator and have use physical keyboard enabled. Let me experiment a bit and update or remove this comment.

Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Ohk, Tried a few stuff! The below answer worked. i.e., manually settings `editText#setInputType` to `0` or `InputType.TYPE_NULL`
Is this approach bad since no one had given any positive recommendations ??

@Yaniv: Once you have confirmed u read my comments, I will delete this post as it won't work. Thanks!

Comment: `editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)` in conjunction with `editText.setFocusable(false)` worked for me [API: 19]

Comment: @VenoM It's Superrbb!!

Answer (score 2):

Put this in Oncreate Method

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: I've tried this but I don't have the method 'getSystemService()' when I extends from Dialog.

Comment: u can pass activity or applicationcontext in ur constructor

Comment: It didn't help, the soft keyboard still appear at the moment I move to the next EditText.

Comment: modify ur manifest,
<activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" android:name=".sampleactivity">
  </activity>

Answer (score 0):

in order to disable ANDROID SOFT INPUT KEYBOARD xml file doesn't help in my case
calling the setInputType method on EditText object in java file works great.
here is the code.

```
EditTextInputObj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextInput);
EditTextInputObj.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: Please don't use so many periods like that. Just one will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the textViews in the view group you can make make the view get the focus before any of its descendants by using this:

```
view.setDescendantFocusability(view.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

Answer (score 0):

by set EditText focusable->false, keyboard will not opened when clicked

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:focusable="false" />
```

Comment: Whilst this code may answer the question, it is better to include a description or extra information on what it does.

Comment: Tried this, but I can't re-enable it even though I set it programmatically to true

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(null);
```

It will disable the keyboard to the textView and the click will not work anymore.