# How does setTextIsSelectable prevent the keyboard from appearing?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-softkeyboard

If I create a simple app with single Activity that contains a single EditText, and I do

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

then this prevents the keyboard from appearing (in my tests on Android 5.0 and 7.1). This is what I want, as requested in these questions:

- [Disable soft-keyboard from EditText but still allow copy/paste?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174606/disable-soft-keyboard-from-edittext-but-still-allow-copy-paste)
- [How to disable Android Soft Keyboard for a particular activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851339/how-to-disable-android-soft-keyboard-for-a-particular-activity)
- [Android: Disable soft keyboard at all EditTexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803193/android-disable-soft-keyboard-at-all-edittexts)
- [How to disable keypad popup when on edittext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611833/how-to-disable-keypad-popup-when-on-edittext)
- [Disable keyboard on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636635/disable-keyboard-on-edittext)

The [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L5607) is

```
public void setTextIsSelectable(boolean selectable) {
    if (!selectable && mEditor == null) return; // false is default value with no edit data

    createEditorIfNeeded();
    if (mEditor.mTextIsSelectable == selectable) return;

    mEditor.mTextIsSelectable = selectable;
    setFocusableInTouchMode(selectable);
    setFocusable(selectable);
    setClickable(selectable);
    setLongClickable(selectable);

    // mInputType should already be EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL and mInput should be null

    setMovementMethod(selectable ? ArrowKeyMovementMethod.getInstance() : null);
    setText(mText, selectable ? BufferType.SPANNABLE : BufferType.NORMAL);

    // Called by setText above, but safer in case of future code changes
    mEditor.prepareCursorControllers();
}
```

But I don't see what about this disables the Input Method from appearing.

Calling the following methods all return `true` whether I set `setTextIsSelectable` or not.

```
editText.isFocusable();             // true
editText.isFocusableInTouchMode();  // true
editText.isClickable();             // true
editText.isLongClickable();         // true
```

I'm partly asking because I'm curious, but also because I need to disable the system keyboard in my app. I want to understand what is happening so that I can be sure that it is really doing what I think it is doing.

**Update**

Follow-up question and answer:

- [How to enable keyboard on touch after disabling it with setTextIsSelectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228531/how-to-enable-keyboard-on-touch-after-disabling-it-with-settextisselectable)

Comment: [Editor.startSelectionActionModeInternal](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/Editor.java#L2009)

Comment: @adneal, So it appears to be because of `!mTextView.isTextSelectable()`. Feel free to add this as an answer. I'm a little curios why making sure that text is not selectable would be a determining factor in showing the keyboard (but that information is not necessary to answer my question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyboard isn't shown when you call `TextView.setTextIsSelectable(true)` and then select text as a result of [`Editor.startSelectionActionModeInternal`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/Editor.java#L2009), which checks if `TextView.isTextSelectable` is `false` before showing the text selection `ActionMode`.

```
    final boolean selectionStarted = mTextActionMode != null;
    if (selectionStarted && !mTextView.isTextSelectable() && mShowSoftInputOnFocus) {
        // Show the IME to be able to replace text, except when selecting non editable text.
        final InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager.peekInstance();
        if (imm != null) {
            imm.showSoftInput(mTextView, 0, null);
        }
    }
```

My guess to why it's implemented this way is probably because the framework team decided they wanted text `Editor` could predict to be selectable to not jump around the screen as a result of the keyboard moving it around. It was probably just a UI decision. According to git it's been that way since 2012, but the commit doesn't mention anything specifically regarding that implementation.