# How to enable keyboard on touch after disabling it with setTextIsSelectable

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using a [custom in-app keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45005691/3681880), so I need to disable the system keyboard. I can do that with

```
editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

for Android API 21+. But to do the same thing down to API 11, I am doing

```
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Sometimes I want to show the system keyboard again after disabling it with `setTextIsSelectable`. But I can't figure out how. Doing the following does show the system keyboard, but if the user hides the keyboard and then clicks the EditText again, the keyboard still won't show.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
```

I guess I could do `editText.setOnFocusChangeListener` and then manually show or hide the system keyboard, but I would prefer to undo whatever `setTextIsSelectable` did. The following also does not work:

```
editText.setFocusable(true);
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText.setClickable(true);
editText.setLongClickable(true);
```

How do I do it?

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227805/how-does-settextisselectable-prevent-the-keyboard-from-appearing)

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**

Doing the following will reverse the effects of `setTextIsSelectable(true)` and allow the keyboard to show again when the `EditText` receives focus.

```
editText.setTextIsSelectable(false);
editText.setFocusable(true);
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText.setClickable(true);
editText.setLongClickable(true);
editText.setMovementMethod(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.getInstance());
editText.setText(editText.getText(), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

**Explanation**

The thing that prevents the keyboard from showing is `isTextSelectable()` being `true`. You can see that [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/Editor.java#L2009) (thanks to [@adneal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45228754/3681880)).

The source code for `setTextIsSelectable` is

```
public void setTextIsSelectable(boolean selectable) {
    if (!selectable && mEditor == null) return; // false is default value with no edit data

    createEditorIfNeeded();
    if (mEditor.mTextIsSelectable == selectable) return;

    mEditor.mTextIsSelectable = selectable;
    setFocusableInTouchMode(selectable);
    setFocusable(selectable);
    setClickable(selectable);
    setLongClickable(selectable);

    // mInputType should already be EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL and mInput should be null

    setMovementMethod(selectable ? ArrowKeyMovementMethod.getInstance() : null);
    setText(mText, selectable ? BufferType.SPANNABLE : BufferType.NORMAL);

    // Called by setText above, but safer in case of future code changes
    mEditor.prepareCursorControllers();
}
```

Thus, the code in the short answer section above first sets `mTextIsSelectable` to `false` with `setTextIsSelectable(false)` and then undoes all of the other side effects one-by-one.