# Disable, reenable and the soft keyboard does not appear on touch

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Take a look at this example:

```
public class TestEditSoftKbdActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    findViewById(R.id.editText1).setFocusable(false);
    findViewById(R.id.editText1).setClickable(false);
    findViewById(R.id.editText1).setEnabled(false);

    findViewById(R.id.editText1).setFocusable(true);
    findViewById(R.id.editText1).setClickable(true);
    findViewById(R.id.editText1).setEnabled(true);

    findViewById(R.id.editText1).invalidate();
    findViewById(R.id.editText1).requestLayout();
}
```

}

After this sequence of calls the edit text view would no longer pop up its soft input method upon being touched :(

Could someone explain what is going wrong here?

Comment: Why are you inflating a view 8 times?

Comment: It could be something simple - try setting enabled before focusable - it's entirely possible that setFocusable doesn't do anything on a disabled view.

Comment: @Delyan - well reasoning, +1 for that alone. Only it did not help no matter how I have rearranged them

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close soft keyboard for your text view follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803193/android-disable-soft-keyboard-at-all-edittexts/5803257#5803257). Here is a solution for you. But you need to define your own TextView to do that. He suggests using;

```
public class NoImeEditText extends EditText {
    public EditTextEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
       super(context, attrs);     
    }      
    @Override      
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {   
        return false;     
    }        
}
```

Hope it works.