# EditText Keyboard disable but the touch focus has to there

Tags: android

I am designing my own keyboard, so i dont want the default keyboard to appear.

I am able to achieve this, but the focus on selection is missing.
How can i have the focus but disable the Keyboard alone on `EditText` in Android?

Comment: try this `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in between activity tag in manifest

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot sorry not working

Comment: Got throw This Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803193/android-disable-soft-keyboard-at-all-edittexts

Answer (score 0):

add this listener for edittext:

```
edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
  if(hasFocus){
      hideSoftKeyboard();
  }
  }
});
```

and add this method to activity:

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard() {
  InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```