# Hiding system keyboard when using customized keyboardView in SearchView on Android

Tags: android, keyboard, searchview

Initially what I want is only to add a camera button to the standard keyboard to navigate to a camera activity. After some research this was achieved by using `keyboardView`. I followed http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm, and it works very well, except when working with `SearchView`.

Clicking the search icon when `SearchView` is iconified will result in popupping both the customized `keyboardView` and the system keyboard.

I tried to override `SearchView.setOnSearchClickListener()` and `setOnFocusChangeListener()`. They didn't work.

My question is how to hide the system keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16480207/1016367) set onTouchListener with these code:

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);      
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)   
{  
    edittext.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);  
    edittext.setTextIsSelectable(true);  
}
```