# How to disable the soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview

I am working on a project  with an AutoCompleteTextView. I've put some buttons to work as a keyboard the problem is when i click(focus) on the autocompletetextview
the soft keyboard appears i dont want it to appear at all i have tried use this .

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

but this seems only to work if i put it in an onclick (button) and it is used to hide the keyboard while i need to disable it completely...any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803193/android-disable-soft-keyboard-at-all-edittexts check this

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    View view = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = 
            (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

You can call this method on button click Maybe this helps you.