# Jetpack Compose: Disable Interaction with TextField

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

Is there a way to disable all interaction for Jetpack Compose's TextField?

Comment: It's a known feature request currently: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166478534

Comment: this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65699135/8362967

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [**`enabled`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#textfield) attribute:

`enabled` : controls the enabled state of the `TextField`. When `false`, the text field will be neither editable nor focusable, the input of the text field will not be selectable, visually text field will appear in the disabled UI state

Something like:

```
var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("Text") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    enabled = false,
    label = { Text("Label") },
    singleLine = true
)
```

Comment: `enabled ` will not act on `disabledTextColor`, is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Do you know some way to make TextField editable and focusable but not selectable?

Comment: To make text non-selectable, wrap the components within `DisableSelection { ... }`

Answer (score 9):

My project is on `alpha08` atm. Hopefully they add some built in way of doing this soon but in the meantime I've been doing this:

```
val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
val disabled = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
Box {
  TextField(value = textState.value, onValueChange = {
    textState.value = it
  })
  if (disabled.value) {
    // Set alpha(0f) to hide click animation
    Box(modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize().alpha(0f).clickable(onClick = {}))
  }
}
```

So yeah, drawing an invisible clickable Box that's the same size over the TextField. You can resize the TextField to whatever you'd want, calling `.matchParentSize()` on the invisible Box will make it match the TextField due to them being the only children in the parent Box.

You can toggle the disabled state by setting `disabled.value = true/false` wherever is appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

`readOnly` attribute can also work in case if you want focusable & selectable text field but not editable.

Like this:

```
   var value by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello World!") }

    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        readOnly = true,
    )
```