# How can I disable a full view in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, disable, composable

I want to disable a whole view from any interaction (e.g. button presses) when a Boolean in my view model is true.  How can I do this in Jetpack Compose without having to disable each of the elements within the view?

See example below as to what I'm trying to do.

```
@Composable
fun MyView(alertViewModel: AlertViewModel = viewModel()) {

    var text by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }

    Column(
        /*

    Disable all elements in the column so I don't need to disable each element individually for example:
    
    modifier = Modifier
    .disabled(
    if (alertViewModel.showAlert == true) {
         true
    } else {
         false
    }

         */
    ) {

        Text(text = "My View")
        
        TextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = { newText ->
                text = newText
            }
        )

        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: use enabled and set it to the value you want for both textfield and button

Comment: So I have to disable the `Textfield` and `Button` separately?  I can't disable the whole `Column`?

Comment: It's a shame this isn't yet possible...

Answer (score 3):

Seems as though it isn't possible to disable a whole view in Jetpack Compose.  All interact-able elements such as `Button` and `TextField` and have to be set to `enabled = false` individually.

Buttons: [Jetpack Compose: How to disable FloatingAction Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847231/jetpack-compose-how-to-disable-floatingaction-button)

TextFields: [Jetpack Compose: Disable Interaction with TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65217799/jetpack-compose-disable-interaction-with-textfield)