# Android. How to set focus on TextField without keyboard poping up in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to set focus on OutlinedTextField which I already do with focusRequester. However by default I don't need the keyboard to pop up, only if the user presses on the OutlinedTextField itself, then the keyboard should pop up.

So basically I would like to disable keyboard pop up at all. Only manual presses on TextFields should pop up the keyboard while also having the ability to set focus.

Edit:
The users are using barcode scanner devices, and they are 90% of the time scanning barcodes. The other 10% they enter the text with the keyboard. That's why i need the focus, but don' initially need the keyboard.

This is my test composable:

```
                    var fieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
                    val focusRequester = FocusRequester()
                    val softwareKeyboard = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

                    var showOutlinedTextField1 by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }


                    Column {
                        if (showOutlinedTextField1) {
                            OutlinedTextField(
                                label = { Text("TEXT1") },
                                value = fieldValue,
                                singleLine = true,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .focusRequester(focusRequester),
                                onValueChange = { enteredValue ->
                                    fieldValue = enteredValue
                                },
                                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                                    imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                                ),
                                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                                    onDone = {
                                        fieldValue = ""
                                        showOutlinedTextField1 = false
                                    }
                                )
                            )
                        } else {
                            OutlinedTextField(
                                label = { Text("TEXT2") },
                                value = fieldValue,
                                singleLine = true,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .focusRequester(focusRequester),
                                onValueChange = { enteredValue ->
                                    fieldValue = enteredValue
                                },
                                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                                    imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                                ),
                                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                                    onDone = {
                                        fieldValue = ""
                                        showOutlinedTextField1 = true
                                    }
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    }


                    DisposableEffect(showOutlinedTextField1) {
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                        softwareKeyboard?.hide()
                        onDispose { }
                    }
```

I tried LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current?.hide() but it doesn't always work, and when it does, the keybaord first pops up and only then gets hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69358766),
Just Wrap your text field with CompositionLocalProvider like below.

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalTextInputService provides null
    ) {
          OutlinedTextField(
                 label = { Text("TEXT1") },
                 value = fieldValue,
                 singleLine = true,
                 modifier = Modifier
                             .fillMaxWidth()
                             .focusRequester(focusRequester),
                 onValueChange = { enteredValue ->
                                fieldValue = enteredValue
                            },
                 keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                            ),
                  keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                                onDone = {
                                    fieldValue = ""
                                    showOutlinedTextField1 = false
                                }
                            )
            )
     }
```

Comment: It does prevent the keyboard from popping up and I get the focus on the TextField. The problem is, when the field is pressed by user, then the keyboard should pop up normally. This prevent the keyboard from showing entirely.

Unless i can make my own LocalTextInputService instead of null, and make it somehow catch the event on textField click. I'll look into that

Comment: Actually, the users are using barcode scanner devices, and this seems to also prevent the scanned barcode from entered into the textField

Comment: @AndriusZ remove the focus requester from the modifier, It will make the keyboard popup after clicking on the textfield.

Comment: .I tiried removing the focusRequester but the keyboard still doesn't show with this method. Also I do need the TextField to be focused, so even if it worked, i would still have an issue.

Comment: I understood your problem, Remove Composition Local Provider as this allows keyboard to open up and Remove focus requester which makes TextField to get focus upon clicking on it.

Comment: No. What I need is the TextField to always have focus automatically. But I only need the keyboard to show if the user presses on the TextField themselves. Your solution disables the keyboard entirely.